# Redirecting multiple ccTLD's to 1 gTLD: delete the 'old' domains in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, top-level-domains

We are planning to redirect our current multiple ccTLD's (`.com`, `.de`, `.nl`) to 1 gTLD with country specific subdirectories (`.com/en`, `.com/de`, `.com/nl`). We will use permanent 301 redirects from the ccTLD to the relevant subdirectories of the gTLD.

With this move, should we delete the multiple indexed ccTLD's in Google Webmaster Tools and only have the new gTLD indexed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with keeping them GWT tools, if you are still going to own the domains.

I might however ask the question why you are moving from country specific TLD to a single domain? Country specific domains are the generally favored over using sub domains on a single TLD.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We are planning to move to a single domain to focus our link building efforts.